# Unable to run JSP file from VSCode

Tags: html, jsp, visual-studio-code

I have made a basic form page in HTML and programmed it such that when I click the submit button, it must go to a JSP page where the details entered will be displayed.

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ABC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="xyz.jsp">
        Name: <input type="text" name="nm" placeholder>
        ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder>
        Submit: <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSP code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>XYZ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String St1 = request.getParameter("nm");
        String St2 = request.getParameter("id");
        out.println("Your name is: " + St1);
        out.println("Your id is: " + St2);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried running the HTML page using the live server in vs code, it shows the page not found after clicking the submit button.

I am literally a beginner and helpless, please tell me what should I do? OR where am I getting it wrong?

I`m using VSCode for the aforementioned.